# Getting ORA-00904: : invalid identifier in oracle application express

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

I want to create this simple table in oracle application express but i keep getting the error

> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

and I have no idea why.

```
CREATE TABLE ArtWork (
    ArtWorkId NUMBER (6,0) CONSTRAINT aw_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR2 (20),
    Desc VARCHAR2 (25)
);
```

Comment: `DESC` is a SQL keyword.  Use a better name, such as `description`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`desc` is a reserved word (it is used to to specifiy the sort direction, for example in an `order by` clause).

You need to either surround it with double quotes, or better yet change your column name to something that does not clash with a language keyword, so you don't need to worry about it later on:

```
CREATE TABLE ArtWork (
    ArtWorkId NUMBER (6,0) CONSTRAINT aw_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR2 (20),
    Description VARCHAR2 (25)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reserved keywords shouldn't be used as identifiers as they are for implicit usages. Hence change `desc` to some other name like `description`